# AttributeError: 'BuildEnvironment' object has no attribute 'sdk'

Tags: xcode, flutter, app-store-connect, codemagic

When I Build ios app using codemagic the publishing phase fails with the following errors.

Details

```
    == Gathering artifacts ==

== Publishing artifacts ==

Publishing artifact vet_mobile.ipa
Publishing artifact Runner.app.zip
Publishing artifact Runner.app.dSYM.zip
Publishing vet_mobile.ipa to App Store Connect
> app-store-connect publish --path /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/vet_mobile.ipa 
--key-id DYJV4Y4NKR --issuer-id b39ecc0a-cc5d-4bf6-a44d-bb96fc007e00 --private-key
@env:APP_STORE_CONNECT_PUBLISHER_PRIVATE_KEY

Publish "/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/vet_mobile.ipa" to App Store Connect

...

./vet_mobile.ipa/SwiftSupport/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib
./vet_mobile.ipa/Symbols
....
./vet_mobile.ipa/Symbols/FFBB712D-D466-3D81-B148-15281753EBBA.symbols

Removing temporary directory /var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn
/T/ipatool20220911-6396-1wniyas...
$ rm -r /var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/ipatool20220911-6396-1wniyas
/Applications/Xcode-13.4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:298:in `locate_tool': 
Couldn't locate otool-classic in /Applications/Xcode-13.4.app/Contents/Developer
/usr/bin 
/Users/builder/.rbenv/shims /Users/builder/.rbenv/bin /Users/builder/.pyenv/versions 
/3.8.7/bin /usr/local/bin /Users/builder/.local/bin /usr/local/share/android-sdk/
emulator /usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-
tools
/usr/local/share/android-sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 /Users/builder/.pub-cache/bin /usr/bin
/bin /usr/sbin /sbin (RuntimeError)
from /Applications/Xcode-13.4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2097:in `<main>'

stdout: ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]
bitcode_build_tool_main(sys.argv)
File "/Applications/Xcode-13.4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../lib      
/bitcode_build_tool/main.py", line 65, in main
env.initState(args)
File "/Applications/Xcode-13.4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../lib
/bitcode_build_tool/buildenv.py", line 159, in initState
self.logger.debug("SDK path: {}".format(self.sdk))
AttributeError: 'BuildEnvironment' object has no attribute 'sdk'


Failed to upload archive at "/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/vet_mobile.ipa"
Failed to publish /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/vet_mobile.ipa
Failed to publish vet_mobile.ipa to App Store Connect.
```

This is happening for flutter 3.3.1, xcode 13.4.1.
I saw some issues like mine but none has working solution [here you can see Build 41 fails LOTS OF ERRORS](https://docs.assembly.digital/codemagic-cicd)

Comment: seems like Apple error https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707487

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: Same error occurred to me. I am using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.